# jQuery string is not defined

Tags: php, javascript

I'm sending data to function by onclick event but I can't get string value I just getting integer value, it say that **'value'** is not defined. what is the problem.

My code is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="begin(<?php echo $data['user_id'];?>,
   <?php echo $data['name'];?>);">
```

This is my function:

```
function begin(id,name)
{
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
}
```

I'm not getting name value, if I pass hard-code string then its also not getting here only integer are accessible.

Comment: Your question is no way related to `jQuery`. Please change the title of your question!

Comment: Yes it is not but first i thought it is related to jquery now problem is solved and i understood it is not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt says, without quotes it won't be recognised.

That said, I don't think his answer is correct. I would prefer this code: (whitespace added for legibility)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="begin(
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data['user_id'])); ?>,
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data['name'])); ?>
);">
```

[`json_encode` (docs)](http://php.net/json-encode) is good for passing any PHP variable (except Resources) into JavaScript. In this case, it will add quotes around the string, and escape characters as needed with backslashes. Since it's going in an attribute, you need `htmlspecialchars` to convert symbols to be safely insertable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your parameters in quotes to make it a string.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="begin('<?php echo $data['user_id'];?>','<?php echo $data['name'];?>');">
```

Comment: You're welcome! Go ahead and click the check mark to mark the question as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: What if the name contains an apostrophe?

Comment: So... is that a big "FU" to my Irish and Arab friends? :p